# jQM1.4 - enhanceWithin() over-riding data-role="none". Why?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm dynamically injecting data by running a search on a string and inserting links into it for linking to a glossary, like this:

```
return '<a href="#glossary" data-role="none" class="glossaryLink" data-transition="slide">' + match + '</a>';
```

The returned string is then appended with `append()` to a div.

This works fine, usually. But because a lot of the text and page elements are dynamically injected I have to call `enhanceWithin()` on the div in order for all the jQM widgets to work (like collapsibles).

`enhanceWithin()` is then giving the glossary links extra classes, which I don't want. These classes are inherited (it seems) and they are making the text into buttons and list items and so on. I want control of how they look so I tried `data-role="none"` and it doesn't work.

Can anyone help?

Comment: it depends where do you append the link. Can you show us an example?

Comment: It's appended in a li tag. If it's appended elsewhere its fine, but in the li tag its gets extra classes added to it.

Comment: `li` inside `ul` with `data-role=listview`, an `a` will be converted into a button. Actually, `li` will be converted into a _clickable_ button and `a` holds the classes, e.g. `ui-btn`, etc...

Comment: I know, that's what's happening. I don't want it to do that though. Why is data-role="none" do nothing and how can I fix this?

Comment: `data-role=none` does nothing because it's within a widget structure, it isn't on its' own. solutions 1) use `ul` without `listview` 2) remove all custom classes after enhancement `$("li a").removeClass("ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r");` 3) replace `a` with `p` and add listeners to it.

Comment: 1)Works but then I lose the other listview formatting I want. 2)Works but messes up the indentation of the list. 3)I tried using span already and the click handlers just don't work at all. I think it's because of the way the text is processed. I don't really know though. That might be why your solution for going to a specific place in the glossary doesn't work.

Comment: My solution works with `listview` http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/W2hjr/1/

Comment: This is a slightly different issue to the last one, though i see why the other issue failed - my links are in the text, not in listviews)